# Login in c# with SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, authentication

I am trying to make a login form using SQLite database, i have created a new table named login, i have added id (pk), username and password fields (both username and password are texts as data type) and i wrote the following code:

```
conn.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from login where username = '"+textbox_id.Text+"' and password ='"+textbox_password.Text+"'", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int count = 0;
while (dr.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("K");
        }
```

I have tried to use parameters but its the same result, nothing happens, no error but count is not incremented for some unknown reason.

Comment: Did you run the command in an SQLite management studio to see what the results of the query were? Have you stepped through it in a debugger? You should not be doing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and then executing a reader again, pick one or the other, not both. If you want to use non-query, use `select count(*) from login...`, which is preferable, then `int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data~Devart.Common.DbCommandBase~ExecuteNonQuery.html) documentation:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.**

So this, will not work:

```
int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You can use [ExecuteScalar](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data~Devart.Common.DbCommandBase~ExecuteScalar.html):

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from ...";
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters aside, you are trying to execute the command twice. Instead of using a loop to count results, just use SQL `Count` to get the number of results.

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select Count(*) from login where username = '"+textbox_id.Text+"' and password ='"+textbox_password.Text+"'", conn);
int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

But definetely change this to use parameters, if somebody typed into either one of your textboxes something like `'; DROP TABLE login` your database would be lost. Even worse, I can read all your passwords since you store them plain-text (another big no-no).

Comment: I did as you said, when i reach the cmd.executenonquery(); it returns value -1 although when i ran the SQL command in manager it returned count as 1

Comment: I apologize,  I meant execute scalar.